# How to Try-Catch or return a success flag when Transaction commits or rollbacked - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a SQL Transaction in a Stored procedure , I want to know how to return a success message in case of Transaction successfully commits or failed at any point ie. rollbacked,I want to use that flag in my code in MVC C# .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code might help you on this,

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- sql update\delete statement goes here 
 COMMIT TRANSACTION    
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      PRINT 'Error ...'
   END 
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS Error#,        
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMsg
END CATCH
```

Comment: so i have to use this Error and ErrorMsg in my code , and for that i have to declare them as out parameter like "Error varchar(20)" and ErrorMsg varchar(20) also in case of success where to return .??

Comment: so i have to use this Error and ErrorMsg in my code , and for that i have to declare them as out parameter like "Error varchar(20)" and ErrorMsg varchar(20) also in case of success where to return .?? @Aditya .

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1739122.aspx?How+can+I+return+a+text+message+error+from+a+stored+procedure+ this link might help you ...

Comment: @ManojKargeti, you can use either `OUTPUT` parameters or a result set to return the success/fail message. In the case of result sets, you could just add  SELECT 0 AS Error#, N'Success' AS ErrorMsg' after the `COMMIT` in the example. The result set should have the same column names and data types for a clean interface.  Alternatively, you could code a single `SELECT` after the `CATCH` to return local variable values assigned in the `TRY` or `CATCH` block so that only one `SELECT` is needed.

Comment: The result set should have the same column names and data types for a clean interface. @DanGuzman could you please give an example of it getting error 'invalid Column name'.. in SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS Error#,        
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMsg..

Comment: @ManojKargeti, query compilation errors in the same scope cannot be caught.  So to catch 'invalid column name', the quey in the `TRY` block will need to be executed dynamically using `EXECUTE` or `sp_executesql` so that it in a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

### You can write as :

declare @success bit = 1

begin transaction
begin try
 --main content of script here
end try

begin catch
    rollback transaction
    set @success = 0
end catch

if(@success = 1)
begin
    commit transaction
end

Comment: could you please give an example for update for better understanding ,